# Flutter code error: type 'Duration' is not a subtype of type 'Timer'

Tags: flutter, datetime, stopwatch, sqflite

I am calculating the duration of the flutter stopwatch, when the user quit the app, I am getting the above type of error, how to convert the duration to DateTime format, it's not working by parsing.

1. Here is the old time, which I am getting from sqflite, where I have stored it as a string, then parsing to DateTime
2. And a new time

   ```
     getData() {

      Future<List<smokingData>> list =
       UserDatabase.instance.retrieveSmokingData();

      list.then((value) => {
       value.forEach((element) {
        _preTime = element.preTime;
       })
      }).then((value) {
      setState(() {
       var predata = DateTime.parse(_preTime);
       updatedTime = newTime.difference(predata);
      });

       print(updatedTime);
   }
   ```

> Pre data is the previous time,  that i have stored in sqflite as
> String

> UpdatedTime is the duration between old and new time

> print(updatedTime)...Gives correct answer in duration which I want to convert to DateTime format

> Finally, i want to assign the the time duration to a StopWatch(which start counting up after the duration time), and to a Flutter Circular Timer

Comment: It should be possible to read and answer questions on stackoverflow without clicking around on several off-site links.

Comment: Hi! Please add formatted code instead screenshot

Answer (score 0):

**Use custom seconds or milliseconds below and see if it works for you**

> Get current date

```
         getCurrentDate() {
            var date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(12345678)
                .toString();

            print("date is + $date");
            var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

            var formattedDate =
                "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year} | " +
                    "${dateParse.hour}:${dateParse.minute}:${dateParse.second}";

            return formattedDate;
          }
```

> 12345678 is example duration which includes all data

Comment: i am not getting your code, what is the filterorder[i]?

Comment: bro your code is useful, do i have to pass the updated time(which is duration b/w previous time and DateTime.now() ), while i am passing it instead of '12345678', i getting error like, 'type 'Duration' is not a subtype of type 'int''

Comment: @navidanchitrali can you update the question with what you have tried. I can help if I can see in what line you are getting type exception

Comment: Please properly structure the code. I'm unable to understand @navidanchitrali